# tracking where unchecked (or checked?) exceptions get lost

Tags: java, exception

how would you track where unchecked exceptions are getting lost? I'm developing a Swing GUI with embedded Processing Views, but somehow exceptions aren't shown on STDERR or anywhere. Everytime I had to go through the whole application through debugging until the error occured. But now it seems to be somewhere in a large loop and I don't get the cause. The stack is as follows:

```
Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running)

Thread [AWT-Shutdown] (Running)

Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Running)

Thread [Animation Thread] (Running)
```

and if I pause the application every thread is suspended (which is normal) and the AWT-Event-Queue thread is in unsafe park, whereas I don't know what this means. I'm almost sure an exception has been thrown somewhere.

best regards,

Johannes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With eclipse (and other IDEs...) you can set a breakpoint to halt when an exception is thrown. Just debug the application, configure the breakpoint (break on an exception type) and the debugger will show where it occured.

Comment: Thanks, it was an assertion error, but didn't show up, which is a bit strange :-/